# Map tiles don't load in Xcode 7.3 Watch Simulator

Tags: ios, dictionary, mkmapview, ios-simulator, watchos-2

This seems to be a known issue as described in [whatchOS 2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/releasenotes/General/RN-watchOSSDK-2.0/index.html):

> If you do not see map tiles load on the Watch Simulator, launch the Maps app in the iOS simulator first. After that, map tiles will load.

I tried these steps, with no success, the map is always showing an empty grid:

- Run the WatchKit app. Then only the WatchKit app launches. In the iOS simulator, I open the built-in Maps app. Map tiles are loaded and shown there. In the Watch simulator, I go to Home and launch my app again. The map remains in yellow empty grid.
- In the WatchKit app, I go to Home and launch its Maps app. Maps neither show map tiles, only the yellow empty grid and an activity indicator.

Has somebody else experienced this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: xCode8 - still same issue, so good news - it's consistent ;)

Comment: anyone know how to fix this? I got same problem with xcode8 watchOS 3.1

Comment: Same problem here... I recommend opening a bug report.

Comment: 6 years later, the problem still persists in Xcode 14.3.